# Docker PHP exec() function: permission denied

Tags: php, docker, permissions, exec, permission-denied

I'm trying to run the exec() function in PHP, but I'm getting a 'Permission denied' output. PHP is installed as a Docker container. I'm getting this on Raspberry PI as well as on my Macbook.

For a test, I installed LAMP without Docker, and it works fine, but on Docker it doesn't.

For example, when I run

```
echo exec('docker --version');
```

I'm getting this info in my PHP script in the browser:

```
sh: 1: docker: Permission denied
```

And it doesn't matter whether I run exec() function or any alternative like shell_exec() or system(). I've been trying everything with no success for the last few days. This must be a docker thing, but I have no idea what it is.

Some things that I tried:

- changed ownership of my .PHP file and dirs where it is located
- changed permissions to 777
- added www-data user to sudoers file
- added www-data to docker group

Comment: Do you need just docker or docker with access to other running containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting indicates the exec is working, but the user that is running the command doesn't have access to the docker binary.

You'll have to modify the permissions inside the docker container to allow the web user to run the docker command.  You will want to add those steps to your `Dockerfile`.

```
RUN chmod go+x `which docker`
```

Should allow any user to run the docker command inside the container, but may be considered a security risk.

---

Note that in the command above, I was thinking you would copy and paste the command directly.  The [`which`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/which) command will locate the docker executable, and the [backticks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27432/33314) that enclose `which docker` will use the output in the `chmod` command, making it unnecessary to know the exact location for the docker executable.

Comment: Thanks Paul for an instant answer. What do I suppose to write in place of "which docker"? I tried `RUN chmod go+x /var/www/html` but it doesn't work. I rebuilt the PHP container and the error persists.

Comment: Actually, I meant literally 'which docker' enclosed in backticks.  [`which`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/which) is a system command that locates the file on the path.  The backticks tell the shell to execute the command and substitue the response, thus you don't need to know the path to the docker executable beforehand.

Comment: I thought so, and I actually tried 'which docker' first, but I was getting errors in red when rebuilding the container. Here's the error: `chmod: missing operand after 'go+x'
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.`. I tried a version with straight quotes (') and then I'm getting this error: `chmod: cannot access 'which docker': No such file or directory`

Comment: Interesting.  I'm not much of a docker guy -- you might need to locate the docker executable yourself and put the literal value in there.  Or, maybe the docker executable doesn't exist inside the container.

Comment: When I insert 'which docker' in console, I get `/usr/bin/docker`. So I tried `RUN chmod go+x /usr/bin/docker`, but then I'm getting this error: `chmod: cannot access '/usr/bin/docker': No such file or directory`. I'll keep trying. Thanks for your help. I'll post an update here when I make it work.

Comment: You might consider using Docker APIs rather than executing the docker utility.  There seem to be several [good PHP wrappers](https://github.com/theodorosploumis/awesome-docker-php) for them.

Comment: I see. However, I'm going to use other commands as well, not just docker's. Mainly I want to use RSYNC+SSH in PHP code.

Comment: Paul, your advice actually worked! Well, sort of. `\`which docker\`` returns `/usr/local/bin/docker` in my case. But 'docker' is not a directory, so instead of `\`which docker\`` or `/usr/local/bin/docker` I used `/usr/local/bin` (no 'docker' at the end), and I don't get the `sh: 1: docker: permission denied` anymore. However, now it shows `sh: 1: docker: not found` - I'm trying to solve this, without much success for now. I guess it's a folder permissions thing...